# maven in netbeans 7.1.1

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm using netbeas 7.1.1 and I know that this version already has Maven support.
anyway if a try to  type in the terminal mvn --version, the command is not recognized.
from the other hand I can create a maven project using the IDE wizard.
so I have to download it anyway?
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Netbeans uses an embedded Maven installation.

Open `Tools->Options->Java->Maven`

where you can see the maven binaries.

If you open the Maven Home dropdown menu, you are going to see a Bundled one (the embedded), and a list of the other maven binaries (for you -> none).

The binary of the bundled maven install is in:

```
<netbeans_install>/java/maven/bin/mvn
```

If you use Linux, you have to add a symlink to maven (mvn binary) in the exectutable locations `/usr/bin`, for example. Doing that will make the os recognize the mvn command systemwide. Or, you can add the  `<netbeans_install>/java/maven/bin/mvn` directory to the list of the executable locations (the `$PATH` system variable).

If you use Windows, you need to add the maven binary to `%PATH%`.

In both cases, you might have to set up `JAVA_HOME` system variable.

So, in short, if you don't want to download a new maven binary, you can use the one bundled with Netbeans. To use Maven in command line, you need to add the path to the maven binary to the PATH variable of your OS.